# Выборка элементов массива при помощи Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется массив. Нужно выбрать из него 3 последовательно расположенных элемента, произведение которых равно заданному числу Number при помощи Linq-запроса. Ниже приведен пример решения задачи с использованием обычного цикла. Кто может помочь с Linq?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArraySimple.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            if (ArraySimple[i] * ArraySimple[i + 1] * ArraySimple[i + 2] == Number)
            {
                Factor1 = ArraySimple[i];
                Factor2 = ArraySimple[i + 1];
                Factor3 = ArraySimple[i + 2];
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вопрос интересный, конечно, но не стоит использовать в продакшене LINQ только ради LINQ. Для таких операций он не предназначен, так что лучше оставить вариант с циклом.

Comment: dog_funtom: не следует считать LINQ бесполезной игрушкой, правильно написанный LINQ-код может быть намного эффективнее "стандартного" кода -- например, за счёт ленивых вычислений (ненужное не вычисляется) и нематериализованных массивов данных (локальность).

Comment: @VladD, я сам пользуюсь им при любой разумной возможности, но не когда приходится писать монстров. Ваш ответ хорош, и мой комментарий не про него, я просто думал, что требуется именно встроенными операторами обойтись.

Comment: @dog_funtom: как и в любой области, нужен разумный баланс. Некоторые пишут всё на LINQ только потому что "так круче", некоторые, наоборот, пишут всегда без него потому что "так эффективнее". Оба подхода не очень.

---
Встроенными операторами, судя по всему, получается громоздко :(

Comment: Согласен, в каждом конкретном случае нужно смотреть по обстоятельствам, и так со всеми технологиями, паттернами, практиками, методологиями и прочим.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для начала, не стоит пользоваться LINQ лишь ради LINQ. Если в вашем коде сравнение троек лишь одно, сделайте циклом.

Однако, код на LINQ может быть более эффективным и выразительным, поэтому если в вашем коде подобное встречается часто, стоит написать следующую LINQ-обёртку (переделана из используемого `Pairwise`):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<R> Triplewise<T, R>(
            this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, T, T, R> selector)
    {
        using (var it = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!it.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            T prevprev = it.Current;
            if (!it.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            T prev = it.Current;
            while (it.MoveNext())
                yield return selector(prevprev, prevprev = prev, prev = it.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Имея это, ваш код легко переписать так:

```
ArraySimple.Triplewise((v1, v2, v3) => v1 * v2 * v3 == Number ?
                                           Tuple.Create(v1, v2, v3) : null)
           .Where(triple => triple != null);
```

Так код стал понятнее, правда?

Пример:

```
var ArraySimple = new[] { 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 12, 1 };
var Number = 12;
var triples = ArraySimple.Triplewise((v1, v2, v3) => v1 * v2 * v3 == Number ?
                                            Tuple.Create(v1, v2, v3) : null)
                         .Where(triple => triple != null);
foreach (var triple in triples)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} * {2} = {3}",
                        triple.Item1, triple.Item2, triple.Item3, Number);
}
```

выдаёт

> 2 * 3 * 2 = 12
> 2 * 6 * 1 = 12
> 1 * 12 * 1 = 12

Comment: код хорошо, но нужно выбирать три последовательных числа, следующих друг за другом, т.е. ответ может быть только один либо вообще его нет.. (массив состоит из ряда упорядоченных простых чисел (3, 5, 7, ..), нужно найти 3 последовательные числа, произведение которых будет равно заданному числу, например 3*5*7=105) как можно модифицировать Ваш алгоритм для моей конкретной задачи?

Comment: @lider112: этот код именно так и делает. Попробуйте такой входной массив: `{ 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6 }` -- он найдёт только (3, 1, 4), но не (2, 1, 6).

Answer (score 4):

Код вышел слишком широким, чтобы писать здесь, поэтому отвечаю через [сервис сниппетов.](http://snipt.org/zfDd4) Данный вариант не требует того, чтобы исходная коллекция была массивом, но с PLINQ использовать, наверное, не стоит.

Comment: Красиво, но страшно. Я даже боюсь сравнивать скорость цикла против этого монстра :)

Answer (score 2):

Если утверждается, что исходник - массив, а не абстрактный Enumerable тогда такой способ сработает:

```
// arr - заданый массив
    arr.Skip(2)
    .Select((it,ind) => new 
                     {
                         Num1 = arr[ind],
                         Num2 = arr[ind+1],
                         Num3 = arr[ind+2],
                     })
    .Where((it)=> it.Num1 * it.Num2 * it.Num3 == Number)
```

Comment: Возникает исключение типа "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" с сообщением "Index was outside the bounds of the array"...

Comment: my bad: с индексами напутал.

Answer (score 0):

Cтруктура результат :

```
struct ResultInt
    {
        public int FirstNumber;
        public int SecondNumber;
        public int ThirdNumber;
    }
```

Метод класса:

```
public static IEnumerable<ResultInt> GetThreeNumbers(int[] InputArray, int Number)
        {

            // создадим запрос линку
            IEnumerable<ResultInt> GetThreeNumbersLinq =
                (from Item in InputArray
                 where (Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item) < SomeArray.Length - 2) &&

                      (SomeArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item)] *
                       SomeArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item) + 1] *
                       SomeArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item) + 2] == Number)
                 select new ResultInt()
                                {
                                    FirstNumber = InputArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item)],
                                    SecondNumber = InputArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item) + 1],
                                    ThirdNumber = InputArray[Array.IndexOf(InputArray, Item) + 2],
                                }
            );
        }
```

Вызов :

```
        int[] InputArray = null;
        int Number= 0;

        List<ResultInt> SomeResult = GetThreeNumbers(InputArray, Number).ToList<ResultInt>();

        foreach (ResultInt item in SomeResult)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.FirstNumber.ToString() + " " + item.SecondNumber.ToString() + " "+item.ThirdNumber.ToString());
        }
```